# Use js if/else with CSS value

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm not really a programmer, but I have to change some html/css/js code for our needs.. and I'm struggling.

we are using a cloud software, which closed source, but with the possibility to change parts of the HTML frontend.

the software uses the CSS class "dom-admin" to hide some setting for non-admin.

```
<div class="dom-admin"> hidden for non-admins </div>
```

if a user logs in, the display property is set by the system to `display:none;`

```
.dom-admin {
    display: none;
}
```

these hidden fields are mostly input fields. we dont want to hide this fields for our users, we just want to set the fields `readonly`.

my idea is to read the display value within a javascript in a if / else query:

```
if (dom-admin('display') == 'none') 
{ document.write('<input type="text" id="XX">') }
else
{ document.write('<input readonly type="text" id="XX">') }
```

My Problem is to access the display value, i tried x examples from the net, but i never able to read the property of "dom-admin", eg:

```
document.getElementById('dom-admin').style.display
```

Chrome Javascript Console:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null

Chrome dev-tools shows me this about the "dom-admin" CSS:

[image]

I appreciate any help...
Thanks, Patrick

Comment: You're trying to use `getElementById` but the HTML is `class="dom-admin"`. Class is not the same as ID. Use `querySelector` instead

Comment: Try [`document.querySelector('.dom-admin')`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) or [`document.querySelectorAll('.dom-admin')`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) or [`document.getElementsByClassName('dom-admin')`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName).

Comment: It will be great if you use a back-end language to show or hide elements! Because you said the elements will be conditionally rendered according to the role

Comment: Note: If you use `querySelectorAll` or `getElementsByClassName` you need to access the element by its index i.e. `document.getElementsByClassName(".dom-admin")[0]`

Comment: Remember to secure form data on server side. Making inputs hidden/readonly only on client site is very bad idea and can causes vulnerabilities.

Comment: Anyone can edit the client-side code, so this would be a pretty obvious security concern. It should be re-enforced on the server

Comment: you are all right - it must be done on the server. i just needed i quick workarround for some weeks..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Phase 1: Reveal All Hidden Field(s)

---

### Multiple Elements with Common ClassName

The class `.dom-admin` is merely presentational, it is not a security measure. If you want to access multiple elements with the className of `dom-admin` you must collect them into a NodeList/HTMLCollection:

```
var DOMObjects = document.querySelectorAll('.dom-admin');
```

OR

```
var DOMObjects = document.getElementsByClassName('dom-admin');
```

---

With this list you'll have to iterate/loop through each `*.dom-admin` by a `for` loop, or array method (if the latter them the list might need to be converted to an array):

```
for (let i=0; i < DOMObjects.length; i++) {...
```

OR

```
DOMObjects.forEach(function(DOMObj, index) {...
```

---

To reverse the style of `.dom-admin`, you can set each `*.dom-admin` `style` object to:

```
DOMObj.style.display = "block"
```

OR remove `.dom-admin` class:

```
DOMObj.classList.remove('dom-admin')
```

---

### Single Element with ClassName

The most direct method is to target the className via `querySelector()` or `getElementsByClassName()[0]`:

```
var DOMObj = document.querySelector('.dom-admin');
```

OR

```
var DOMObj = document.getElementsByClassName('dom-admin')[0];
```

---

## Phase 2: Set All Revealed Fields to be Non-editable

---

### Set/Get/Change Element Attributes

`id`, `class`, `readOnly`, etc. are called attributes.  The attribute needed has a Boolean value (true/false). An attribute such as `readonly` merely needs to exist on the tag in order for it to be true. Not actually be in the tag of course makes it false.

**Set an attribute**
More specifically, adding an attribute to an element when it didn't exist before:

```
DOMObj.setAttribute('readonly', true);
```

---

**Get an attribute**
Finding an attribute and reading the value of said attribute:

```
DOMObj.getAttribute('readonly');
```

---

**Change an attribute**
If the attribute already exists and the value needs to be changed:

```
DOMObj.removeAttribute('readonly')
```

---

Keep in mind that the attribute you are dealing with has a Boolean value so it is handled differently than an attribute with a String value.

```
DOMObj.setAttribute('name', 'foo'); /*OR*/ DOMObj.name = "foo"

DOMObj.getAttribute('name');

DOMObj.setAttribute('name', 'bar') /*OR*/ DOMObj.name = 'bar'
```

---

#### Note 1

The syntax for methods `querySelector()`/`querySelectorAll()`:

```
document.querySelector('.dom-admin')
```

CSS Selector ===========^-----^[dot for class]

is different than the syntax of method `getElementsByClassName()`:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('dom-admin')
```

DOMString====================^------^[no dot needed]

```
document.getElementsByClassName('dom-admin')[0]
```

DOMString====================^------^===^-^[no dot needed]==

[Bracket Notation with index of zero is needed if there is only one target]

---

#### Note 2

**Do not use `document.write` unless you intend to destroy everything on your page.**

If you have inputs nested within the `div.dom-admin`, that would mean that those inputs exist already ***but the user cannot see them***. It isn't necessary to create them and even if you do need to create any element, never use `document.write`. Instead use `createElement()` or use `innerHTML` on an element that you intend to use as a container.

---

### Demo

```js
// Collect all .dom-admin into NodeList
var das = document.querySelectorAll('.dom-admin');

// forEach() .dom-admin, remove the class .dom-admin
das.forEach(function(da, idx) {
  da.classList.remove('dom-admin');

  // Find all inputs in the div formerly known as .dom-admin
  var inputs = da.querySelectorAll('input');

  /* forEach() input nested within the div formerly known 
  || as .dom-admin, set its attribute readonly to true
  */
  inputs.forEach(function(input, index) {
    input.setAttribute('readonly', true);
  });
});
```

```css
.dom-admin {
  display: none;
}

input {
  font: inherit;
  width: 40%
}
```

```html
<div class="dom-admin">
  <input type='text' value='These inputs exist already'>
  <input type='text'>
</div>

<div class="dom-admin">
  <input type='text' value='Do not use document.write'>
  <input type='text' value='it will overwite EVERYTHING'>
  <input type='text' value=''>
</div>

<div class="dom-admin">
  <input value='Fun fact:'>
  <input value='input by default is type="text"'>
  <input>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I used to achieve what you want.

As others mentioned, use `document.querySelector('.dom-admin')` to access the class and when you change `display` style, you can use the if statement

```js
let admin = document.querySelector('.dom-admin');
if (admin.style.display === 'none') {
  document.write('<input type="text" id="XX">');
} else {
  document.write('<input readonly type="text" id="XX">');
}
```

```css
.dom-admin {
  width: 200px;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="dom-admin">
  <form action="#">
    <input type="text" id="user" />
    <input type="number" id="user_number" />
    <input type="password" id="user_password" />
    <input type="submit" id="submit" />
  </form>
</div>
```